# Unity script crashes editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (shipController.Mode == ShipController.ShipMode.Build)
        {
            var mouseInWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
            Debug.Log(mouseInWorld);
            var mousePos = new Vector2(mouseInWorld.x, mouseInWorld.y);
            var currentPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            var posToTarget = mousePos - currentPos;
            var oldPosToTarget = posToTarget;
            var oldPos = currentPos;
            var shotPastTargetOrExact = false;
            var iter = 0;
            while (!shotPastTargetOrExact)
            {
                iter++;
                Debug.Log(iter);
                oldPos = currentPos;
                oldPosToTarget = posToTarget;
                if (posToTarget == Vector2.zero) shotPastTargetOrExact = true;
                if (Mathf.Abs(posToTarget.x) >= Mathf.Abs(posToTarget.y))
                {
                    if (posToTarget.x > 0) currentPos = new Vector2(currentPos.x += blockdistance, currentPos.y);
                    else currentPos = new Vector2(currentPos.x -= blockdistance, currentPos.y);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (posToTarget.y > 0) currentPos = new Vector2(currentPos.x, currentPos.y += blockdistance);
                    else currentPos = new Vector2(currentPos.x, currentPos.y -= blockdistance);
                }
                posToTarget = mousePos - currentPos;
                if (posToTarget.sqrMagnitude > oldPosToTarget.sqrMagnitude)
                {
                    shotPastTargetOrExact = true;
                    currentPos = oldPos;
                }
            }

            if (currentSlot != null && currentSlot.CurrentItemDragAndDrop != null && currentSlot.CurrentItemDragAndDrop.Item != null)
            {
                var item = currentSlot.CurrentItemDragAndDrop.Item;
                if (currentPlacementBlock == null)
                {
                    currentPlacementBlock = Instantiate(item.BlockPrefab);
                }
                currentPlacementBlock.transform.localPosition = currentPos;
                currentPlacementBlock.transform.rotation = shipController.transform.rotation;
            }
            else if (currentPlacementBlock != null)
            {
                Destroy(currentPlacementBlock);
                currentPlacementBlock = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

It crashes when I try to stop the game with the play button in the editor. It has also crashed when starting build mode (see shipController.Mode)

The script works as intended but crashes when stopping the game.
I loged the iterations to try and see if it was looping forever but it doesnt seem to be that as it always comes out with a small iter number in the console

Comment: what exactly is your while loop supposed to do?

Comment: While loops are usually culprits of editor crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by checking if the mouse was in the window before going ahead and performing the rest of the update

```
bool IsMouseOverGameWindow { get { var mousePosition = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue(); return !(0 > mousePosition.x || 0 > mousePosition.y || Screen.width < mousePosition.x || Screen.height < mousePosition.y); } }
```

Comment: and what if your app later runs in fullscreen?